# How to fix "Issue: Violation of Families Policy Requirements"

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I've tried to publish an app on Play store but it's rejected and I've received an email titled: "Issue: Violation of Families Policy Requirements"

And it also followed by: "Apps that contain elements that appeal to children must comply with all Families Policy Requirements. We found the following issue(s) with your app:

Eligibility Issue
<>
In order to review your app for “Designed for Families” eligibility, we will need you to provide a test login account. Please provide login credentials to the support team before you submit any updated version for another review (select “Test Login Needed” and include the test login account and password details in the open box field)."

I sent the test login account and password as requested, and I'm sure that my app doesn't violate Families Policy Requirements that includes these items:

https://play.google.com/about/families/children-and-families/families-policy/

I've received the same email several time without any further detailed information about this issue.

How can I contact Play_store to Know more about my Problem?

Comment: We have the exact same thing - our app is being rejected due to "Test Login Needed". However, we did provide the Test Login info in Play Console (App Content -> Target audience and content -> Instructions for app access); also, once we got rejected, we followed the instructions and submitted the same info via the linked web form (from the rejection email). We also tried resubmitting and doing everything from scratch like 5 times total - always the same result. So either we're crazy and our test login credentials aren't working (which we checked many times) or their system is bugging out.

Comment: btw did you manage to get published in the end? if yes, how?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We had the exact same issue (see my comment under the question) and what eventually got us published was changing our "Target age group" configuration in Play Console (App Content -> Target audience and content -> Target age group) - we unchecked everything below `13-15`. Not sure if you had those checked, but if you did, try unchecking them then resubmit the app.

I realize that we basically had to lie and are now maybe risking some penalty (getting removed from the Play Store?) but doing everything right got us nowhere, so we had to resort to this "cheating".

Not saying you should do what we did, just saying what worked for us. Do it at your own risk.

Comment: I had the same issue and the problem is solved when I follow your answer. After I selected the age group `13-15` I selected `No, my store listing does not appeal to children` in the next tab which led to this message "Your app is not enrolled in the Designed for Families program"

Comment: You are  correct, for "Policies" we compromise to fair  "cheating". Ridiculous!

Comment: The whole thing is not clear to the developers, especially these which does not fall under USA laws and restrictions, and write usually more or less local for their groups applications.

Answer (score 4):

Google Play updated the Polices on regular bases here is the new Policy...

**Families Policy Updations**

Step 1: Login with google play account

Select Your App to Publish and select Release Management-->> App Release from left side corner as below..
[image]

Step 2 : Click on the App Content option and follow the screens

[image]

Question 1 : Click on Start option and Complete all the questions and submit as follow

[image]

answer the correct age group to which your app support.

Example : i selected 18 and Above

[image]

Question 2 : Does it appeal to children give your answer

Example : i selected NO because my app not appeal to children

[image]

Submit : Click on Next and finally Submit

[image]

Final Step Go Back and select your app which you want to update select Release Management>> App Release... now you wont find any error...

@Ambilpura

Comment: This will not work for the app which is intended for bellow 18.

Answer (score 3):

Check your privacy policy. I had also like this issue, then I provided privacy policy.

Comment: After providing the privacy policy, do we need to create new release with new build, or just sending updated app content for review will be enough?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the latest way to add test credentials in the Play Console:

1. Open Play Console and go to the [App content page](https://play.google.com/console/app/app-content/summary) (Policy > App content).
2. Under "App access," select Start (or If you’ve previously added instructions for app access and you want to make changes, you’ll see and select Manage instead of Start.)

[image]

3. Click + Add new instructions and provide your access details.

[image]

4. Use the “Any other instructions” field to let us know if there’s anything special about your login mechanism, such as using a one-time password, multi-factor authentication, or logins with more than two fields. Then, press the "Apply" button.

[image]

Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859455?visit_id=637584518828340026-1664302252&rd=1#app_access

Answer (score 1):

Add valid Privacy Url in App Content 
and use This easy **Privacy and Policy GENRATOR** [Click here](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to "Blocking controls" under app-level on your admob page and check "Ad content rating".