# Why is the update for my app getting rejected in the Google Play Store although I submitted the test login needed many times?

Tags: google-play

I have an app in Google Play.The app is in Family Programs Settings. Its working well. Suddenly i got a mail from google that your app updates has been rejected because you have not submitted the test login needed.So i have added test login needed

1) Login in play console publish account
2)Target audience and content and 
3) In that instruction for app access i have provided test user name and password.

Even after providing  the test user id and password. I have released one version.But after that also i got a mail  that your app has been rejected because we need test login needed.

I have  contact  google play through mail  and provide password also. But again again i have rejected for same reason. Test login needed.

I have uploaded 3 builds  and same build has been rejected for test login needed.I am waiting for past 15 days.

My Question is  Is there any other separate content that allows to type the username and password in google play console or target audience content is enough?

Why My App rejected for same reasons(test login needed) even after providing 
test users password multiple times?

Can any one help me?

Comment: Have no solution for you, just wanted to share that we have the exact same issue (however, in our case, our initial app release is being rejected). We did everything the same as you (provided the test login info in both Play Console and via web form that was linked in the rejection email) and keep getting rejected (like 5 times total now). Found this SO question for the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027059/how-to-fix-issue-violation-of-families-policy-requirements

Comment: btw did you manage to get published in the end? if yes, how?

Comment: @stojke my app got published.stojec,you will receive mail from google play in the topic Feedback from Google play about your App. In this mail 
you will notice Eligiblity issue. In that click support team link button. It will goes to  Appeal an app rejection from Designed for Families.Fill the necessary details.They will sent  one mail. From that mail you can contact them. in case if you need help you can mail me at karthikeyan1982@gmail.com. I will assist you .